# Which preposition to use when talking about the speed of processing a document?

Tags: prepositions

Talking about a software that processes documents, do I say

"Thanks to its completely different architecture, **on** a typical document, it is about ten
times faster."

or

"Thanks to its completely different architecture, **with** a typical document, it is about ten
times faster."

or perhaps even something else?

Comment: Note that the *default* position of your two "fronted" adverbial clauses is *after* the main clause. *It is about ten times faster **with / on / when processing / to process** a typical document [, thanks to its completely different architecture],* if that perspective helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both **on** and **with** sound plausible. Another option is **for**. Without more familiarity with the context/genre it is hard to say which is most natural.